# How do I list all objects of certain type in solution in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, search

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and am working in a large C# solution.  I want to get a list of all enums in the solution.  Can I do this?  The object browser doesn't seem to allow me to filter to certain types of objects.  (Also curious how I would get a list of all classes, interfaces, methods, etc.)

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatically or are you looking for some software that'll do it for you?

Comment: No, not programatically, just in the IDE. I'm trying to find out if VS2010 already does it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find `enum`s generically I think your best bet is Find with Look In: = "Entire Solution"(shortcut Shift+Ctrl+F). Expand "Find options" check Use: and select "Regular expressions" in the dropdown. And Find: = "(public|private|internal) enum".

Comment: Using text-based search isn't what I'm looking for.  I'd need to search "internal enum", "private enum", etc as well, and I'd rather avoid it. The funny part too is that sometimes it doesn't find them all.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better way. But a regular expression could handle the problem regarding the access modifiers. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Searching "public enum" so far is the best way I can see to do it.  And actually, it's weird, it DOESN'T find them all.  It stops after a few searches saying "Reached end of document".  And yes I'm searching the entire solution for "public enum", with "Match case" enabled.

Comment: Interesting. That really must be a large solution, I haven't experienced that problem with Find

Comment: When I search for "(public|private|internal) enum" with "Regular expressions" enabled, it finds about 3 of them, then hits a particular one, and after that each time I click "Find Next" I get "Passed the end of the document" and it won't search any further.  There's some enums I know exist that the search never got to before this happened.

Comment: What happens using the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+F so the button's text is "Find All"?

Comment: I think there is just a bug in Visual Studio with my search.  That specific enum that my search was stopping on, well, when I deleted it, my search continued and worked.  Doing this also allowed Find All to list them all.  When I put that particular enum back, the search breaks.  There must be something about the way that enum is positioned that is breaking the search (absolute mystery at this point). Anyway, after doing that, I was able to list all my enums to an acceptable extent.

Answer (score 3):

From `Visual Studio` VIEW-> CLASS VIEW , after from the filter, like from image 
[image: Class View Window]

select only "Show only base types", and in `search text box` type "enum".

Should mantion that I have Italian language `Visual Studio`, so menu items I translated to english by myself, may be in English version the name is not exactly the same, but I hope it will give you a hint by the way.

Comment: When I do this in my solution, I have thousands of results, several of them methods with names like "GetEnumerator()" and "EnumHelper" classes.  Very few of them are actually enums.

Comment: Yes, tried "Show Base Types", and tried combinations of these buttons.  I think for this to work I would need to be naming all of my enums "XXXEnum", which I'm not.  This seems to search names of symbols only.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are looking out for this but you can view a class diagram of your project on a right-click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33864ckt.aspx

Comment: How does this help me list enums in my solution?

Comment: this wont show you the enums but it gives information about all of your classes and relationships/methods, I dont think there is anything in the VS IDE that can let you find list of enums.